# Thousand separator in histogram axis in R

Tags: r, histogram

I would like to see the x-axis numbers in my histogram in thousand separated format. So for example,

```
y <- seq(10000, 100000, 10000) 
hist(y)
```

in this plot, I want to see 10,000 20,000, etc. on the x-axis. Any simple way to get it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Draw the histogram without an x-axis, then add it manually with `axis`:

```
y <- seq(10000, 100000, 10000) 
hist(y, xaxt="n")
axis(side=1, at=axTicks(1), 
     labels=formatC(axTicks(1), format="d", big.mark=','))
```

`axTicks` calculates the tickmark locations, and `formatC` formats the numbers.  Here is the result:

[image: Hisogram]

Answer (score 3):

The `scales` library has a function called `comma` which formats the numbers how you want:

`library(scales)`

Not quite what you wanted, but a start:

```
q<-quantile(y,prob=seq(0,1,.1));hist(y,breaks=q,labels=comma(q))
```

Better version, using `lattice`:

```
q<-quantile(y,prob=seq(0,1,.1));histogram(~y,breaks=q,scales=list(at=q,labels=comma(q)))
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I write this: Error in plot.histogram(r, freq = freq1, col = col, border = border, angle = angle,  : 
  could not find function "comma".

Comment: @amobishoproden Sorry, thought I'd included the `library(scales)` part.